# Regular expression email issue

Tags: regex

In my email regex i want following output

```
abc@abc.co.in
```

I am writing down below

```
^[\w]+@[a-z]+([.a-z]+)
```

Issue is coming in `.co.in`

I want to iterate the ".co" part not more then 2 times and it should be more then 1 and less then or equals to 2
I tried below but not working

```
^[\w]+@[a-z]+([.a-z]{1,2})
```

Comment: more than 1 and <= 2 is just 2

Comment: Even if you debug your issue, your regex will reject many valid email addresses. One example would be email addresses based on domains containing hyphens. Another example is international domains. You would be better off using an email address API in your language of choice for validating email addresses.

Comment: See http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this.    `\w+@\w+(\.\w{2}){2}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the `.` out of your character class and escape it:

```
^\w+@[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+){1,2}$
```

Also changed your `[\w]` to `\w` and added a `$` to the end so that the whole string must match, not just the beginning.

Comment: @Dan Right, I forgot to escape it! Thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: Now this is exact match. What's the meaning of \ before dot ?

Comment: \ escapes the dot. Since `.` by default has a special meaning in a regular expression (it is a wildcard so it matches all characters). To put match a `.` in the expression you need to escape it with a \

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
^\w+@[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+){1,2}
```

Note that your `[\w]` element is unnecessary, `\w` is sufficient.

Comment: It means that it is a literal period. If there was no `\ ` there, then that dot would actually match any character (except a newline). It wasn't necessary before because it was inside a character class, but when you take the `.` outside of the `[]`, it gains a special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

your dot in this case means "any character". it must be escaped. try this:

```
^[a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*@[a-z]+[a-z0-9\-]*\.[a-z]{1,2}\.[a-z]{1,2}$
```